# How to get Superset Token?? (for use Rest api)

Tags: apache-superset

I attempted to request a REST request to see the document below. But do not work. https://superset.apache.org/docs/rest-api

request: `curl -XGET -L http://[IP:PORT]/api/v1/chart`

response: `{"msg":"Bad Authorization header. Expected value 'Bearer <JWT>'"}`

The Superset installation has been on PIP and was also Helm Chart. But all are the same. helm: https://github.com/apache/superset

How should I order a REST API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

open http://localhost:8080/swagger/v1, assuming http://localhost:8080 is your Superset host address
then find this section
[image]

the response would be like this

```
{
    "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJmcmVzaCI6dHJ1ZSwiaWF0IjoxNjU0MzQ2OTM5LCJqdGkiOiJlZGY2NTUxMC0xMzI1LTQ0NDEtYmFmMi02MDc1MzhjZDcwNGYiLCJ0eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwic3ViIjoxLCJuYmYiOjE2NTQzNDY5MzksImV4cCI6MTY1NDM0NzgzOX0.TfjUea3ycH77xhCWOpO4LFbYHrT28Y8dnWsc1xS_IOY",
    "refresh_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJmcmVzaCI6ZmFsc2UsImlhdCI6MTY1NDM0NjkzOSwianRpIjoiNzBiM2EyZDYtNDFlNy00ZDNlLWE0NDQtMTRiNTkyNTk4NjUwIiwidHlwZSI6InJlZnJlc2giLCJzdWIiOjEsIm5iZiI6MTY1NDM0NjkzOSwiZXhwIjoxNjU2OTM4OTM5fQ.OgcctNnO4zTDfTgtHnaEshk7u-D6wOxfxjCsjqjKYyE"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @Ferris for this visual solution!

To add to this, you can also create the appropriate API call with Python just like following:

```
 import requests

 api_url = "your_url/api/v1/security/login"
 payload = {"password":"your password", 
            "provider":"db",
            "refresh":True,
            "username":"your username"
 }
 response = requests.post(api_url, json=payload)
 # the acc_token is a json, which holds access_token and refresh_token

 access_token = response.json()['access_token']

 # no get a guest token
 api_url_for_guesttoken = "your_url/api/v1/security/guest_token"
 payload = {}

 # now this is the crucial part: add the specific auth-header
 response = request.post(api_url_for_guesttoken , json=payload, headers={'Authorization':f"Bearer {access_token}"})
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the security section of the documentation you have linked. It has this API ​`/security​/login`, you can follow the JSON parameter format and get the JWT bearer token. Use that token to send in the Header of your other API calls to superset.

Answer (score 2):

I thought I would share, since it took me a couple of days to sort this out. If you are aiming to programmatically import things using curl, this is how I was able to do it. This is for a development server and passwords are in plain text. Obviously, use proper precautions when transitioning to a production server.

```
json=$(curl -k 'http://localhost:8088/api/v1/security/login' \
        -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
        -d '{"password": "admin", "provider": "db", "refresh": true, "username": "admin"}') \
&& access_token=$(echo $json | sed "s/{.*\"access_token\":\"\([^\"]*\).*}/\1/g") \
&& echo "access_token = $access_token"

json=$(curl --location GET "http://localhost:8088/api/v1/security/csrf_token/" --header "Authorization: Bearer $access_token") \
&& csrf_token=$(echo $json | sed "s/{.*\"result\":\"\([^\"]*\).*}/\1/g") \
&& echo "csrf_token = $csrf_token"

curl --location --request POST "http://localhost:8088/api/v1/dashboard/import/" \
--header "X-CSRFToken: $csrf_token" \
--header "Authorization: Bearer $access_token" \
--form "formData=@dashboard.zip;type=application/x-zip-compressed" \
--form "overwrite=true"
```

Comment: Any idea why we have to generate a csrf_token to be able to access the api?  using the bearer token is not enough....

Answer (score 1):

Thank @andrewsali commented on [this github issue](https://github.com/apache/superset/issues/2488#issuecomment-358429474), I finally figure out how to access the superset REST API by python code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
def get_supetset_session():
    """
    # http://192.168.100.120:8088/swagger/v1
    url = f'http://{superset_host}/api/v1/chart/'
    r = s.get(url)
    # print(r.json())    
    """
    superset_host = '192.168.100.120:8088' # replace with your own host
    username = 'YOUR_NAME'
    password = 'YOUR_PASSWORD'

    # set up session for auth    
    s = requests.Session()
    login_form = s.post(f"http://{superset_host}/login")
    # get Cross-Site Request Forgery protection token
    soup = BeautifulSoup(login_form.text, 'html.parser')
    csrf_token = soup.find('input',{'id':'csrf_token'})['value']
    data = {
        'username': username,
        'password': password,
        'csrf_token':csrf_token
    }
    # login the given session
    s.post(f'http://{superset_host}/login/', data=data)
    print(dict(s.cookies))
    return s
```

---

DEMO

```
# s = get_supetset_session()
base_url = 'http://192.168.100.120:8088'
def get_dashboards_list(s, base_url=base_url):
    """## GET List of Dashboards"""
    url = base_url + '/api/v1/dashboard/'
    r = s.get(url)
    resp_dashboard = r.json()
    for result in resp_dashboard['result']:
        print(result['dashboard_title'], result['id'])

s = get_supetset_session()
# {'session': '.eJwlj8FqAzEMRP_F5z1Islay8jOLJcu0NDSwm5xK_r0uPQ7DG978lGOeeX2U2_N85VaOz1FuxVK6JIHu1QFhGuEOk5NG8qiYGkJ7rR3_Ym-uJMOzJqySeHhIG8SkNQK6GVhTdLf0ZMmG6sZGQtiQ1Gz0qYiUTVoHhohZthLXOY_n4yu_l0-VKTObLaE13i2Hz2A2rzBmhU7WkkN1cfdH9HsuZoFbeV15_l_C8v4F4nBC9A.Ypn16Q.yz4E-vz0gp3EmJwv-6tYIcOGavU'}
get_dashboards_list(s)
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]